# Getting Max ID from 2 tables with LINQ 2 SQL

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, c#-3.0

I have a 'var' that contains results from two tables using LINQ to SQL.  I need to get MAX(table1.ID).  But I can't do:

```
myVar.table1.ID.Max()
```

since myVar has no idea about the objects it is holding.  What should that syntax look like?

EDIT:

The full query is:

```
var myVar = from table1 in db.table1s
            join table2 in db.table2s
            on table1.empid equals table2.empid
            where table2.deptid = deptid
            select table1
```

Several results are returned.  I want the max table1.ID row.

Comment: Please show us more of your code. It's very unclear what you're doing at the moment. See http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Just remember that LINQ is really a set of methods to be performed on a collection, not a single parameter. Whatever aggregate/predicate/etc LINQ methods you plan to use will be performed on your collection object (IQueryable or IEnumerable). Lambda/anonymous methods just provide an easy way to create a predicate (Func<T, bool>), selector (Func<T1, T2>), or action (Action<T>) delegate inline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, it looks like you want:

```
var maxId = myVar.Max(x => x.ID);
```

Or if you may not have any entries:

```
var maxId = myVar.Max(x => (int?) x.ID);
```

Then `maxId` will be `null` if it's empty.